# Cannot compile C++ code on Linux, but can on Mac OS

Tags: c++, linux, compilation, compiler-errors

For a project I am working on I wanted to try out the following program:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/tirg/

It consists of two C++ files, but I cannot get it to compile on my laptop running Linux, while it compiles without any problem on the laptop of a friend of mine running Mac OS. I have no experience whatsoever in compiling C++ code, so it might be a beginners mistake.

The laptop running Mac OS that managed to compile the code without problems used the following g++ version:

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

I tried compiling the C++ files using gcc, g++, clang and clang++ on my laptop running Arch LInux (64 bit) with the following versions:

```
gcc and g++ (GCC) 4.8.1 20130725 (prerelease)
clang version 3.3 (tags/RELEASE_33/final)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
```

The error I get when compiling it is:

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits/stl_vector.h:1240:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::vector<std::vector<unsigned char> >::_M_fill_assign(int&, int&)’
         { _M_fill_assign(__n, __val); }
                                    ^
```

Which was caused by this line of code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<trg::Rgb> > a(300, 255);
```

I have put the complete output of the compilation on pastebin:
http://pastebin.com/m285PSrH

I also had problems when compiling OpenCV, so there is probably something wrong with my configuration. I think it is a versioning problem, a wrong version of the standard library for example.

Hopefully someone with more experience in C++ can point out what might have gone wrong. Thanks!

Comment: what is max's cpu arch?

Comment: Is that line suppose to create a 300x255 matrix or 300 vectors with each of those subvector elements init to 255?

Comment: Yeah, it is supposed to create a matrix, so 300 vectors containing 255 RGB values. So it is meant as the size of the vector, not as a value. The matrix is used to store the pixel values of the image.

Comment: @Zaibis, my laptop running Arch Linux supports 64-bits. It contains the following processor: Intel Core 2 Duo Mobile SU7300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-g++-4.2 does it wrong.
You would get an 2D vector of vectors if an implicit conversion is possible.
However [23.3.6.2]:

> explicit vector(size_type n);

You may do:

```
struct Rgb {};
int main() {
    std::vector<Rgb> rgb_vector(255);
    std::vector<std::vector<Rgb> > a(300, rgb_vector);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
std::vector<std::vector<trg::Rgb> > a(300, 255);
```

has no sense.
you wanted to write something like this:

```
//std::vector<std::vector<trg::Rgb> > a(picHeight, picWidth);
std::vector<std::vector<trg::Rgb> > a;
a.resize(picWidth);
{   
        std::vector<std::vector<trg::Rgb> >::iterator end = a.end();
        std::vector<std::vector<trg::Rgb> >::iterator it = a.begin();
        for(; it != end; ++it)
                it->resize(picHeight);
}
```

you should correct each assign() in your code and each call to constructor of

```
vector<vector<XX> >
```

Comment: Thanks! That solution does indeed works correctly, but do you perhaps know why it does work on my friends laptop running a different version of GCC. Because indeed, the manual of the standard library says it should not work, but apparently my friend and the author of the C++ code were using some version in which the line of code did made sense.

Comment: GCC 4.2 is 6 years old; there might well have been a bug in its standard library back then.

Comment: Ok, so it was just bad luck that this was my first experience with compiling C++.